# ruby array pack and unpack functionality in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

What are the JavaScript functions or libraries that are equivalent to Ruby's pack and unpack functions for the Array class?  I'm particularly interested in converting hex strings to strings.

```
irb(main):022:0> ["446f67"].pack("H*")
=> "Dog"
```

I'm not a JavaScript programmer and would rather not roll my own converter if libraries are available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JavaScript has a function that does quite the same thing; pack seems to be a Ruby specific. If you're using pack to turn an object into a string, which can be sent over a network, you could use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) instead. The [Prototype library](http://prototypejs.org/) provides methods for turning objects into JSON-encoded strings. There are also Ruby libraries for working with JSON (encoding and decoding) such as:

http://flori.github.com/json/

Comment: I rolled my own using basic string methods.  It was embarrassingly simple.  Hello, Javascript.

Comment: @HappyCoder, any chance you could share your embarrassingly simple pack and unpack methods?

Comment: function hex2string(hex)
{
 i = 0;
      ascii = "";
 while (i < hex.length/2) 
 {
   ascii = ascii+String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2),16)
) ;
  i++;
 }

 return ascii;
}

Sorry for the late reply.  Didn't see your query until now.  I don't think I implemented the reverse in Javascript.  Hope this code helps.

Answer (score 0):

answered here: [pack / unpack functions for node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605108/pack-unpack-functions-for-node-js)