# pack / unpack functions for node.js

Tags: javascript, struct, node.js, pack, unpack

Are there any modules that provide pack / unpack functionality for nodejs similar to python's struct module? I haven't found any specifically for node, and I'd assume that javascript implementations would be significantly slower.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack appears to be a straight-up port of Python's `struct` API for packing binary data, but it's implemented in JS. It doesn't appear to be packaged for npm yet.

https://github.com/substack/node-binary provides unpacking, also implemented in JS, and you can install it with `npm install binary` if you have npm installed.

Comment: No need for a package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655784/php-pack-unpack-implementation-in-javascript-mismatch

Comment: I've also made https://github.com/natevw/struct-fu which lets you define structures with a C-like feel and pack/unpack them.

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/ryanrolds/bufferpack is another solution

Answer (score 0):

[jBinary](http://jdataview.github.io/jBinary/) is another tool in this space which seems to be actively maintained (as of late 2014). It includes [sample specifications](https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary.Repo/tree/gh-pages/typeSets) for a variety of well-known formats, e.g. tar, ico and mp3.