# pack for javascript and return a binary string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did my homework before, so i'm aware of other questions like [pack / unpack functions for node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605108/pack-unpack-functions-for-node-js)

the point is, those packs, return everything but a binary string. What i would like to do is a simple:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > [1,"10.0.0.1","foo"].pack 'l! a4 Z*'
 => "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0010.0foo\x00"
```

Comment: Can you explain the intent of your example?  It is very specific and unclear why you would do this - you pack the number 1 as a native-endian signed long, four bytes of the string "10.0.0.1", and the string "foo" null terminated.  Or are you just looking for a general purpose "pack/unpack" library like in Ruby?

Comment: a generate a binary string that will be mapped to a C struct. the ruby code works, i can exchange information through a svipc between my ruby (perl, python as well) code and my C code. but with javascript, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node.js [v0.5.0-pre Buffers](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/doc/api/buffers.markdown) have various "write" methods which include explicit signedness and endianness.

So your example would be transliterated from Ruby to node.js JavaScript like:

```
var b = new Buffer(8/*long*/ + 4 + 4);
b.writeInt32(1/*value*/, 0/*offset*/, 'little'/*endian*/);
b.write('10.0', 8/*offset*/);
b.write('foo\0', 12/*offset*/);
b.toString();
// => '\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000010.0foo\u0000'
```

**[Edit]:** Updated the link to the [Buffers documentation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/doc/api/buffers.markdown) directly in the GitHub repository.

Comment: Please recommend usage of 0.4.8 instead of 0.5.0-pre.

Comment: @Raynos but 0.4.8 doesn't support it

Comment: @VP it doesn't ? Have you checked?

Comment: @Raynos: the [0.4.8 Buffer docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/buffers.html) don't mention those methods, so even if they exist in that version I doubt that they are "officially supported", whatever that means ;)

Comment: but i'm not able to cast the string at my c side.

Answer (score -2):

Using JS, use the **myVar.toString(2)** where 2 is the radix. This will return a binary value in 1's and 0's.

Comment: can you provide an example in JS as mine in ruby?

Comment: @VP Your question says nothing about Ruby. Your title says JS. There are not even Ruby tags on the question.

Comment: feel free to improve the question, add the necessary tags. you have enough reputation for it ;)