# Different HMACs generated by nodejs and php

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography

```
// base64-encode the binary result of the HMAC computation
$merchantSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$signData,pack("H*" , $hmacKey),true));
```

The above is the php code that generates the digest.

```
let h = crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacKey).update(keyString).digest('base64');
```

The above is the nodejs code that generates the digest. The key that I am using is hexadecimal in both php and node. What should I be doing differently in node to get the same result as that in php. I know php uses a different encoding than nodejs. But, what else am I missing here?

Comment: If you want to make a case that they are different, then you need to show example inputs and outputs.

Comment: @ArtjomB. here is the php code: http://codepad.org/hCIM1J6a
node: http://rextester.com/AEZ83950

Answer (score 1):

well, there are no difference between the hmac's in both php and node.js .

this is the normal behavior for the two pieces of codes your provided.

in your php you are `packing` your `$hmacKey`

the step which is not exists in your node side;

---

in all the next examples i will use **`123456`** as hmac key and **`yello`** as a data string

for example :

**php** without packing :

```
$merchantSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$signData, $hmacKey,true));
echo $merchantSig; // output : gKjrFq1nrRP33vGiAK9V1Z5bLX5EFZhcfy2flRIGPEI=
```

**node.js** without packing :

```
let h = crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacKey).update(keyString).digest('base64');
console.log(h); // output : gKjrFq1nrRP33vGiAK9V1Z5bLX5EFZhcfy2flRIGPEI=
```

---

now let's pack the both :

**php** with packing :

```
$merchantSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$signData,pack("H*" , $hmacKey),true));
echo $merchantSig; // output : Y8D5crzxQfFkwQn1OJHeZTS1KVuTH0y7qLuxyetE0TY=
```

**node.js** with packing *[`here is the trick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962257/2359679)*

```
var h = crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacKey.packHex()).update(keyString).digest('base64');
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^
console.log(h); // output : Y8D5crzxQfFkwQn1OJHeZTS1KVuTH0y7qLuxyetE0TY=
```

---

### Update

Here is some online tests for both php & nodejs in the two cases (using pack-without using pack)

php : https://3v4l.org/HCt4g

nodejs : http://rextester.com/YNNWN69327

here is another tests with another keys and strings . for php :

https://3v4l.org/JKdNk

and node.js

http://rextester.com/RXGM49887 ,

Comment: Did you get the same output after using that 'packHex' function in the nodejs code?

Comment: @KarthikPriyadarshan I've added online demos to check out both php and nodejs tests

Comment: both your code and key string contain hex characters

Comment: here is another tests with another keys and strings . for node.js http://rextester.com/RXGM49887 , php : https://3v4l.org/JKdNk

Comment: I need it to work for that key and string that I gave you

Comment: you may need to handle it by your self , this will be better for you, I've gave you the way, you need to go on ;)