# php base64_encode result not similar to javascript encode result

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Code snippets:

php:

```
$shaVal = '59bc125840733ea828f42e276661b01e177f1414';

$enc = base64_encode(pack('H*', $shaVal));

echo $enc;

//prints => WbwSWEBzPqgo9C4nZmGwHhd/FBQ=
```

and in Javascipt I used `buffer` npm module

```
let Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

let shaVal = '59bc125840733ea828f42e276661b01e177f1414';

//function similar to php's pack() and returns binary data 
let bData = Buffer.from(shaVal, 'hex').toString();
console.log('bData ', bData)

//encode with base64
let val64 = Buffer.from(bData, 'binary').toString('base64');
console.log('base 64 encode ', val64)

//prints => Wf0SWEBzPv0o/S4nZmH9Hhd/FBQ=
```

How can I get the exact same output printed by php?

Note: Both options showing binary data as Y�X@s>�(�.'fa�

Answer (score 2):

It's because PHP pack returns string, where as javascript buffer returns Array.

This answer might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962257/3086531