# Javascript's pack function does not match with php's pack function

Tags: javascript, php, pack

In my project, I need to create a hash secure string in the client(javascript) and send it to the server(php). The server checks valid 
hash secure string or not before doing another stuff.

But the problem is the secure hash string generated in javascript does not match with the secure hash string generated in PHP.

I've already tried [this related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655784/php-pack-unpack-implementation-in-javascript-mismatch) but it does not seem to work in my case.

Here is my PHP code

```
$message = '123';
$secure_secret = 'e5e9fa1ba31ecd1ae84f75caaa474f3a663f05f4';
$pack = pack('H*', $secure_secret);
$hash = hash_hmac('SHA512', $message, $pack);
var_dump('pack: ' . pack('H*', $secure_secret));
var_dump('hash: ' . $hash);
```

The above echos these:

```
b"pack: åéú\e£\x1EÍ\x1AèOuÊªGO:f?\x05ô"
"hash: 5a7c65c2d0ec43b9c5fc255f36518fa3e6083d40db848768309e272973c200c4f3085466fd852cffbd962ec54cd0bd716d0deee6d76899943875d8da56143585"
```

And here is the javascript code(I'm using [locutus's pack function for js](http://locutus.io/php/misc/pack/)):

```
var message = '123';
var secure_secret = 'e5e9fa1ba31ecd1ae84f75caaa474f3a663f05f4';
var pack = pack('H*', $secure_secret);
var hash = crypto.createHmac('SHA512', pack).update(message);
console.log('pack: ' + pack);
console.log('hash: ' + hash)
```

Result:

```
pack: åéú£ÍèOuÊªGO:f?ô
hash: 2ab66f2f2b79968549f2744f55ab50b6b3249812d5c45d54b7fb2b24ceb173e3437dc191150bb4d3972a81ec7ea420fb5b58d9e5d4c9ba567d85566410d7508f
```

But if I change the $secure_secret string with another simpler string, such as '321' then the results will be matched.

PHP:

```
$message = '123';
$secure_secret = '321';
$pack = pack('H*', $secure_secret);
$hash = hash_hmac('SHA512', $message, $pack);
var_dump('pack: ' . pack('H*', $secure_secret));
var_dump('hash: ' . $hash);
```

Result

```
"pack: 2\x10"
"hash: deefdd44d55c5fe786ed3f1c09e3b32f32459dd885a970fe01091fecc17ef12162080c011e58fb7cd2f420a070f48c27ba19be9b92f07081a6f7908536f3eed9"
```

Javascript:

```
var message = '123';
var secure_secret = '321';
var pack = pack('H*', $secure_secret);
var hash = crypto.createHmac('SHA512', pack).update(message);
console.log('pack: ' + pack);
console.log('hash: ' + hash)
```

Result:

```
pack: "2?"
hash: deefdd44d55c5fe786ed3f1c09e3b32f32459dd885a970fe01091fecc17ef12162080c011e58fb7cd2f420a070f48c27ba19be9b92f07081a6f7908536f3eed9
```

So how can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Look like maybe a typo on the JS. `secure_secret` compared with `$secure_secret`.

Comment: By the way, are you intending to deploy this JavaScript into a web page? Because if you do, then your "secure secret" will not be secret any more - anyone who loads the web page can view the JavaScript code and see the secret. You could potentially obfuscate it, but you can't hide it entirely

Comment: Ok I have found a way to fix this error: use md5 function to hash the pack function then the results will be matched.

Comment: Ok. So was there a typo or not? Was that relevant? And would you like to answer my other question?

Comment: @ADyson No there was not a typo. Actually, I'm using Vuejs for the client, and I store secure secret in .env, so it's kindly safed.